# int array to a string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, int

I'll try be as clear as possible here but basically. (I'm doing this in c)
I have an array (dynamic) of unsigned long long int's that is growing from a while loop.
The workings of that are not anything fancy but I have some getter functions that give info based on what's asked.

Ie. get the first 20 numbers. this returns an unsigned long long int array of length 20 elements.

so the user will pick the number of elements on the returned array, so it could be 1 or it could be 20 large numbers (ie array[]= (1233, 123444, 1234124, 1243124, .....)

I need to get that into a string. I am putting that into a UDP packet. 
I am toying with sprintf but I'm no c expert so any help would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the return value of `sprintf()` for how many character printed.

Comment: What is the exact format of the desired output string?

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way would be to iteratively `snprintf` each element into a buffer.

Here's a function that emulates Python's [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_LEN(x)         (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))

/**
 * Print an array of unsigned long long integers to a string.
 * Arguments:
 *   buf      Destination buffer
 *   buflen   Length of `buf'
 *   ar       Array of numbers to print
 *   arlen    Number of elements in `ar'
 *   sep      Separator string
 * Returns:
 *   The number of bytes printed
 */
int join_ull(char *buf, int buflen,
    unsigned long long ar[], int arlen, const char *sep)
{
    int i;
    char *p;
    const char *end = buf + buflen;

    /* While we have more elements to print, and have buffer space */
    for (i=0, p=buf; i<arlen && p<end; ++i) {
        p += snprintf(p, end-p, "%llu%s", ar[i],
             (i<arlen-1) ? sep : "");        /* Print separator if not last. */

        /* Note that p is advanced to the next place we want to print */
    }

    return p-buf;
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long ar[] = {1, 2, 3};
    char buf[1024];

    join_ull(buf, sizeof(buf), ar, ARRAY_LEN(ar), " ");
    printf("Output: \"%s\"\n", buf);

    /* Test the buffer-too-small case */
    join_ull(buf, 4, ar, ARRAY_LEN(ar), " ");
    printf("Output: \"%s\"\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Output: "1 2 3"
Output: "1 2"
```

Comment: elegant! just elaborate on printing the `(` `)` mentioned in the question

Comment: @chouaib Not sure if the OP *actually* wants `( )` or not.

Comment: Ha... Well that works, be it I only half understand it but I'll mess with it. Thanks you very much!

Comment: @beasts I've tried to add comments everywhere explaining what's going on. Feel free to ask if there's more I've glossed over.

Comment: If I had known about this a year ago... -_- but no, I wrote a custom lib for it because I thought you could only do it to files or the standard output.

Comment: Thanks Jon. the only question I have as I have pretty much got it figured is if I wanted to put say 3 number per line.

I could go,
p += snprintf(p, remain, "%llu, %llu, %llu\n", ar[i], ar[i+1], ar[i+2],);  but then it would be out of bounds if it was not an even mod.

Comment: @beasts Yes, but remember to check for the boundary conditions! For example, what if the last line should only have one entry? You want to make sure you don't overrun `ar` (access elements after the end).

Comment: yeah that is my question. how to you check that boundary in this ex. as even with my limited c exp I know this is bad. I don't quite understand the finer points of building that string in this sense. I guess this is what I get for learning java first :P

Comment: One way would be to have three cases:  If you have just 1 element left, just print one. If you have just 2 elements left, just print two. Otherwise, print all three. You can see how I check this end-of-array case when deciding whether to pass `sep` or `""` for the last argument to `snprintf`.

Comment: awesome thank you very much, I'll play with it tonight. I might have another question or 2 but I have it doing what I want mostly it would just be playing around.